# Can I reuse the Windows Task Manager graph control

Tags: windows, winapi

I would like to use the Windows Task Manager graph control in one of my applications. Is there an API available?

Comment: No. Those are private window classes (`CvChartWindow` in case of the Windows 10 Task Manager).

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for this control. It is private to the OS. You will have to find a 3rd party custom control, or create your own.